# Primefaces dialogReturn

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog from which I can create a person entity, which may be called from various buttons and different fields may need to be updated depending on the current view.

The Persons Dialog is the following:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <!--CREATE DIALOG-->
    <p:dialog header="Create Person" widgetVar="dlgCreatePersons">
        <h:form id="createPersonsForm">

            <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="dlg-full-width">
                ....various fields
            </h:panelGrid>


            <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="@form :messages"
                                 process="@this @form" actionListener="#{person.create}"/>                                                          
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>

        <p:ajax event="close" update="createPersonsForm" global="false"
                listener="#{person.reset('createPersonsForm')}"/>
    </p:dialog>

</ui:composition>
```

On some other form I may have a command button that opens this dialog that updates some part of the page depending on the current view and also may fire a different listener.

```
  <p:commandButton value="+" type="button" onclick="PF('dlgCreatePersons').show()">                      
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="@form" listener="#{bean.doStuff}/>             
   </p:commandButton>
```

So  as you see above I tried to apply the example here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkData.jsf

I understand that this has to do with dialogs that are called from within backing beans, rather than clientside however I was wondering if there is a way to trigger the **dialogReturn** event in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

`dialogReturn` gets triggered when the dialog is being closed.
You can close the dialog via javascript with `￼￼dlgCreatePersons.hide()`. Although the documentation doesn't say something about this event in connection with the javascript API.
Since 4.0 there's also the possibility to close a dialog from a backing bean:

```
public void selectCarFromDialog(Car car) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(car);
}
```

See [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation), Dialog Framework.